# What is the Lange's viewpoint on laws of nature?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, possible-worlds, necessity

I am just wondering what is the Lange's philosophical perspective on laws of nature and what line of thought he follows in the contemporary debate.

Comment: [Friedrich Albert Lange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Albert_Lange) ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I am thinking about Marc Lange.